SimpleDirectoryReader() function seems not to support the Folder or Directory option
I am building a chatbot using FastAPI and Llamaindex tools. When I tried to generate the embeddings of the documents in the ./data directory, the system processed for a long time and raised an error like this:
D:\FastAPI_llama_chatbot\my-chatbot\backend>python -m poetry run generate
INFO:root:Creating new index
INFO:app.engine.loaders:Loading documents from loader: file, config: {'use_llama_parse': True}
INFO:app.engine.loaders.file:Data directory: data
WARNING:app.engine.loaders.file:Failed to load file documents, error message: No files found in data. . Return as empty document list.
INFO:root:Finished creating new index. Stored in storage

Even though I put a lot of data in the ./data directory, I still got the error. I tried logging the file and found the problem in the files.py. If I use SimpleDirectoryReader(input_files=["path/to/file1", "path/to/file2"]), it will work. However, it will be hard for me if there are more than 100 files in the ./data directory.
file.py

def get_file_documents(config: FileLoaderConfig):
    from llama_index.core.readers import SimpleDirectoryReader
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    logger.info(f"Data directory: {config.data_dir}")

    # Ensure the data directory exists
    if not os.path.exists(config.data_dir):
        logger.error(f"Data directory {config.data_dir} does not exist.")
        return []

    try:
        ##### THIS IS THE PROBLEM! #####
        reader = SimpleDirectoryReader(
            input_dir="./data/", recursive=True
        )
        ###################################

        if config.use_llama_parse:
            # LlamaParse is async first,
            # so we need to use nest_asyncio to run it in sync mode
            import nest_asyncio

            nest_asyncio.apply()

            parser = llama_parse_parser()
            reader.file_extractor = {".pdf": parser}

        documents = reader.load_data()
        logger.info(f"Loaded {len(documents)} documents.")
        return documents
    except Exception as e:
        import sys, traceback

        # Catch the error if the data dir is empty
        # and return as empty document list
        _, _, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
        function_name = traceback.extract_tb(exc_traceback)[-1].name
        if function_name == "_add_files":
            logger.warning(
                f"Failed to load file documents, error message: {e} . Return as empty document list."
            )
            return []
        else:
            # Raise the error if it is not the case of empty data dir
            raise e


Can anyone suggest me a solution to this problem? Thank you

Please do not repeat tag information in the post title. The tag system here works very well and doesn't need help, so adding the tags to the title is just unnecessary noise. In addition, [ask] says that if for some unusual purpose you have to add the tags (such as a specific version number where a tag doesn't exist yet), you should not surround them in brackets. Brackets are used to identify closed and duplicate questions, and should not be used for any other purpose.,
